# docker build failed at 'Downloading mariadb'

Tags: docker, mariadb, suse, zypper

Executing 'docker build -t $name .' failed at following issue. It shows 'mariadb_config not found', but i already installed mariadb on this suse15 linux server.

```
Collecting mariadb==1.0.4
  Downloading mariadb-1.0.4.tar.gz (66 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxx0giq5/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxx0giq5/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-hicsuruq
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lxx0giq5/mariadb/
    Complete output (17 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lxx0giq5/mariadb/setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        cfg = get_config(options)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lxx0giq5/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 59, in get_config
        cc_version = mariadb_config(config_prg, "cc_version")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lxx0giq5/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 29, in mariadb_config
        "mariadb_config not found.\n\nPlease make sure, that MariaDB Connector/C is installed on your system.\n"
    OSError: mariadb_config not found.

    Please make sure, that MariaDB Connector/C is installed on your system.
    Either set the environment variable MARIADB_CONFIG or edit the configuration
    file 'site.cfg' and set the 'mariadb_config option, which should point
    to the mariadb_config utility.
    The MariaDB Download website at <https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/>
    provides latest stable releease of Connector/C.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

And related Dockerfile content is as follows.

```
FROM python:3.6.5

WORKDIR /slic-scripts

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "/slic-scripts/run_cmd.sh"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jonathan Jacobson wrote, you need to have the MariaDB Connector installed in your Docker image before proceeding with `pip install`.

Since `python:3.6.5` is based on debian stretch, the connector offered there is 2.3.2 which is not supported by the `mariadb` module (as stated in the [prerequisites](https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/install.html#prerequisites)). To fix this, you might want to switch to a different image (e.g. 3.6-buster).

Here's a working test:

```
FROM python:3.6-buster

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -yy install libmariadb-dev

WORKDIR /slic-scripts
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "/slic-scripts/run_cmd.sh"]
```

Comment: Thank you. But my linux server is suse15, so added 'RUN zypper -n update && RUN zypper install libmariadb-dev' to Dockerfile. 

Then hit the following issue.

Step 5/9 : RUN zypper -n update && RUN zypper install libmariadb-dev
 ---> Running in afdf5d71f900
/bin/sh: 1: zypper: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c zypper -n update && RUN zypper install libmariadb-dev' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: your system and the docker image might use different distros. e.g. I was on arch when I tested that.

Comment: sorry, i cannot understand your comments. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: sure. copy and paste what I wrote without changing anything and run a build.

Comment: Great! It works now, but failed at docker run. I will create another question, hope you can help point out errors. Thank you!

Comment: great catch. there should be a hint in the docker or pip maridb site mentioning that

Answer (score 2):

You need to install MariaDB Connector/C inside the Dockerfile, before running `pip3 install`. It doesn't help that you installed it on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Install MariaDB Connector/C using the below command, which is a dependency.

`sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev`

`RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`